# How to click a JavaScript button programmatically from WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to get WKWebView to load this calendar page (csbcsaints.org/calendar) and immediately go to the next month by clicking that arrow button. Following along with WWDC 2014's 'Introducing the Modern WebKit API,' here's what I have so far:

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    let jsString = "document.getElementById('evcal_next').click()"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let script = WKUserScript(source: jsString, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.addUserScript(script)

        let myConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        myConfiguration.userContentController = contentController
        myConfiguration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: myConfiguration)
        self.view = webView
        if let url = URL(string: "https://csbcsaints.org/calendar") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }

}
```

When that didn't work with either `.atDocumentStart` or `.atDocumentEnd`, I tried calling `webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString)` after loading the page instead, but it only returned an error:

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 
"A JavaScript exception occurred" 
UserInfo={
  WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, 
  WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=
    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('evcal_next').click'),
  WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=38,
  WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=about:blank, 
  NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred
}
```

It seems to say that the command I passed was invalid, but I'm not sure, since running `jsString` in Safari's console  performed the effect I wanted. I'm relatively experienced with Swift and iOS, but new to JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems to be you are trying to click before rendering the element

Comment: I just realized that I didn't say I tried both .atDocumentStart and .atDocumentEnd. Edited.

Comment: i dont know the exact syntax for swift but i am sure problem is the element was not there   let jsString = "document.getElementById('evcal_next') ? document.getElementById('evcal_next').click() : document.getElementById('evcal_next') "

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the delegate of the `webView` like:

```
webView.delegate = self
```

and do it inside `didEnd...` method:

```
extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        /* This is where you can perform DOM with JS in webview */
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the answer? Does it help?